# How to make arguments without `-` or `--` before?

Tags: python, argparse

I was mostly inspired by [git](/questions/tagged/git) for this. Here is a part of my alarm app:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument(
    '--time',
    metavar="HH:MM:SS",
    help='time in 24 hour format separated by colon'
)

group.add_argument(
    '--show',
    action='store_true',
    help='show the list of set alarms'
)

alarm = parser.parse_args()

if alarm.time:
    writeTimeToTheDatabase()

if alarm.show:
    extractTimeFromDatabase()
```

This works very well at this point, as soon as I remove the `--` from both the arguments. I get a `ValueError` which is something similar to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./alarm.py", line 65, in <module>
    help='time in 24 hour format separated by colon'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1295, in add_argument
    return self._add_action(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1515, in _add_action
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional
```

It talks about mutually exclusive arguments but I think traceback is not very relevant to the actual problem.

Comment: you can have a step before initializing the parser to check the first argument.

Comment: @JBernardo can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make your program take arguments in the form

```
./yourprog time
```

or

```
./yourprog show
```

then either you want to use [subparsers](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers), or you should just have your program take a single "command" argument that determines what it does. If you want the `time` and `show` commands to take their own arguments, you want subparsers; otherwise, a "command" argument would be easier. Simply removing the hyphens makes your arguments required, positional arguments instead of named, optional arguments. That's not what you want, and it's not compatible with "mutually exclusive".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in fact you don't want two exclusive arguments, but just one, "command". It's the case for a positional argument.

```
parser.add_argument('command', choices=['time', 'show'],
                    help='one of \'time\' or \'show\'')
alarm = parser.parse_args()

if alarm.command == "time":
    writeTimeToTheDatabase()

if alarm.command == "show":
    extractTimeFromDatabase()
```

Comment: Hmm.. does it let specify HH:MM:SS after `./alarm.py time`?

Comment: For that you'll have to use nmax to consume two arguments, or create a second positional argument. Either way, you will have to check in your own code if you don't get 'time' and 'value', or just ignore the second argument if the command is not 'store'.

Answer (score 1):

In your initial setup, `--time` and `--show` are both optional arguments, and by putting them in the group, you are telling the parser that they both can't be used at the same time.

By removing the `--` you've turned them into positionals.  By default a positional is required.  It doesn't make sense to put both in an mutually exclusive group.

You could make `time` optional:

```
group.add_argument('time', nargs='?')
```

`show` with `store_true` cannot be made optional, since it requires 0 args.  Even when not in an exclusive group, a `store_true` positional does not make sense (though it is allowed), since its value will always be `true`.  So it has to remain `--show`.

A group with an `optional`, and an optional `positional` (yes, I am using 'optional' in two senses here) is possible, and may in some cases make sense.

But as others suggest, you could use subparsers instead.

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp=parser.add_subparsers()
show=sp.add_parser('show')
show.add_argument('show',action='store_true')
time=sp.add_parser('time')
time.add_argument('time')
```

With this `show` produces `Namespace(show=True)`, and `time 12:34:56` produces `Namespace(time='12:34:56')`.